# Data not appearing in template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a view with both a form for user input and an area that displays previously entered data. The form is displaying correctly, but not the data from the db. I'm not sure if it's not saving in the first place, if it's not being queried correctly, not being passed to the context correctly, or not being displayed in the template.

models.py

```
class Channels(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    total_views = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    subscribers = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
class ChannelNameForm(forms.Form):
    channel_name = forms.CharField(label='Add Channel', max_length=500)
```

views.py

```
def add_channels(request):
    queryset = Channels.objects.all()
    print queryset
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ChannelNameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                name = name_config(form.cleaned_data['channel_name'])
                yturl = get_id_url(name)
                sub_count = get_sub_count(yturl)

                c = Channels(name=name, subscribers = sub_count)

                c.save()

            except:
                error = "No results were found for YouTube user %s." % name

    else:
        form = ChannelNameForm()

    return render(request, 'channel_tracker/addchannel.html', {'form': form,'queryset' : queryset})
```

addchannel.html

```
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<form method='get'>
{% for item in queryset %}
    {{ item.name }}
    {{ itm.subscribers}}

{% endfor %}
</form>
```

Comment: So what does the template look like?

Comment: Sorry, updated with the template

Comment: Why do you have `<form method='get'>` wrapping around your for-loop in `addchannel.html`?

Comment: I don't know, I think I was just throwing things at the problem at the time

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to specify the action url, you can put:

```
 <form action="{% url 'add_channels' %}" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that I was trying to insert a str into an IntegerField, and no error was raised because of the goofy try: except: statements.